# how to get the value of a column in recordset with space in the name?

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic, whitespace, recordset

we have change the server of our client, i'm trying to get rid of all the errors i got in the new server, i've got this situation:

yesterday, on the old server this works fine:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName INNER JOIN tableName2 ON tableName.Code = tableName2.[Global dimension 1 code] WHERE [No_]="&request("aNumber")
set rs = conn.execute(sql)

if not rs.EOF then
subCat = rs("Global dimension 1 code")
else
subCat = 0
end if
```

today, on the new server with IIS6 and same sql server 2008 as the oldone, i get the variable "subCat" empty, BUT if i write:

```
subCat = rs("code")
```

it goes good. Also:

```
do until rs.EOF
  for each x in rs.Fields
    Response.Write(x.name)
    Response.Write(" = ")
    Response.Write(x.value & "<br>")
  next
  Response.Write("<br>")
  rs.MoveNext
  loop
```

gives all the columns, also those with spaces, and things like:

```
subCat = rs("[Global dimension 1 code]")
subCat = rs("'Global dimension 1 code'")
subCat = rs("[tableName].[Global dimension 1 code]")
```

rise a 500 server error.

anyone has a hint to point a column in recordset with spaces? i'm usign ASP classic.
thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `select field1,field2...` in place of `select * ...`

Comment: mh, not yet, i'll try, but this could be a course for me, this was an example select, in my case i have a select with at least 50 columns to select, and many, many, many SQLs. btw i'll try this asap and tell.
on the other hand making SELECT *, [global dimension 1 code] AS code1 seems to work.

Comment: The explicit SELECT seems to work fine, i'll start to change all the queries accordingly :( thanks Flakes (if you write the answer insthead of a comment, i'll close the thread)!!

Comment: usually gives such kind of errors for syntax error. go to the lines and check the code

Comment: @polin not really, when the server is not configured to send detailed error messages each and every error will give 500 server error. (Same with IE having show friendly errors)

Comment: @peorthyr off topic for this question, but you REALLY better change your code to use Parameters instead of adding the raw value from Request to your SQL statement. [Here is](http://www.userfriendlythinking.com/Blog/BlogDetail.asp?p1=7013&p2=119&p7=3001) a good blog post plus sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly specify the fields to be selected :

```
Select fieldname1, fieldname2 from ...
```

instead of

```
Select * from ...
```